# HttpSession as a parameter in the controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpsession

I am trying to understand how to sending HttpSession as a parameter in the spring controller works.
I have a jsp which does a post request on clicking the submit button. In the controller, reading the sessions as follows

In the controller:

```
public ModelAndView viewEditFundClass(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Model model){
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)request.getSession();

java.util.Date startDate = sesseion.getAttribute("startDate");
```

However, when I just change the controller to the following, I am still able to access the session

```
 public ModelAndView viewEditFundClass(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session,Model model)
```

I would like to know how this is done in Spring, ie how did the post request pass the HttpSession as a parameter? will this session be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Spring 3+ `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` handler methods, Spring defines a default set of [supported argument types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) for your handlers

> - Session object (Servlet API): of type `HttpSession`. An argument of
>     this type enforces the presence of a corresponding session. As a
>     consequence, such an argument is never `null`.

Spring uses the strategy pattern to accomplish this, using the interface [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html). It checks the parameter types of your handler methods and, for each type, tries to find a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that will be able to resolve an argument for it.

For `HttpSession`, that implementation is [`ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.html).